# What does the term MANAGED in a load balancing scheme indicate?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

The load balancing scheme is an attribute on the forwarding rule and backend service of a load balancer and indicates whether the load balancer will be used for internal or external traffic. The possible values are EXTERNAL, EXTERNAL_MANAGED, INTERNAL, and INTERNAL_MANAGED.

My queries are as follows:

- What does `*_MANAGED` indicate?
- Why do we need and `EXTERNAL_MANAGED` over `EXTERNAL` and similarly why do we need `INTERNAL_MANAGED` over `INTERNAL`
- Traffic Director has a load balancing scheme of `INTERNAL_SELF_MANAGED`? What does the term `SELF_MANAGED` indicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be found in the GCLB [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https) so I'd suggest to read it next time.

> What does *_MANAGED indicate?

In this context, it means it uses a [Envoy proxy](https://www.envoyproxy.io) implementation which is ***managed*** by Google and from here its name. As well a `MANAGED` and `non-MANAGED` schemes are implemented in the Google Front Ends (GFEs), both use a different approach.

> Why do we need and EXTERNAL_MANAGED over EXTERNAL and similarly why do we need INTERNAL_MANAGED over INTERNAL

There are some recommendations on when to use one or another but the main difference is the Envoy Proxy. There are some capabilities which are documented in details for [external ones](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https) and [internal ones](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/l7-internal)

> Traffic Director has a load balancing scheme of INTERNAL_SELF_MANAGED? What does the term SELF_MANAGED indicate?

Indicate the same as its name. That is a service which is self-managed because  its [fully managed by GCP](https://cloud.google.com/traffic-director/docs/features) and works on its own in the sense of maintainability. In addition to this, to avoid confusion with the `INTERNAL_MANAGED` term.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. With regard to `*_MANAGED`, you say 'it means it uses a Envoy proxy implementation which is managed by Google'. When you say managed by Google, what does that exactly mean? Does it mean it adds its own functionality over Envoy proxy?

Comment: It means it is administrated and maintained by Google.